# Using MATLAB calculating infinite integration

Tags: matlab, infinity, symbolic-integration

I work with symbolic toolbox,
and here is my code：

```
syms x h
g=(1-x).*(1-x+h);
int(g,-inf,inf)
```

and the result is ：

```
ans = piecewise([h in R_, Inf], [0 < sign(Im(h)) and h in R_, Inf + i*Inf], [sign(Im(h)) < 0 and h in R_, Inf - i*Inf])
```

the answer I calculated was：`1/3-0.5*h+1/6*h^3`

and I want to get this answer using MATLAB

Are there some way to get it？

Comment: Either your calculation is wrong or you've typed something incorrectly above. That integral does not converge on `[-Inf Inf]`. Mathematica confirms this. You should also tell the `int` function which variable you'd like to integrate with respect to, i.e., `int(g,x,-inf,inf)`. If you know anything about `x` and/or `h` (e.g., > 0, Real, etc.) you should use [`assume`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html) to help the Symbolic Toolbox solve such equations.

Comment: Try `int(g,x)` - that gives you `x^3/3 + (- h/2 - 1)*x^2 + (h + 1)*x`. And then figure out how that function behaves.